# SQL - Time difference between rows, conditional

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a database for logging peeing/pooing time for a puppy. Each row contains a timestamp `datetime`, and bools `pee` and `poo`.

I'm trying to add a column for the time since last pee/poo. The verbose version of this column would be:

> subtract this row's `datetime`
>
> from `datetime` of the row
>
> with the highest `datetime` that is lower than this row's `datetime`
>
> and that has a `poo` value of 1

The basic query is:

```
SELECT 
    d.`datetime`,
    d.`poo`,
    d.`pee`/*,
    column with time since last poo as `poo_diff`,
    column with time since last pee as `pee_diff` */
FROM 
    `diary` d
WHERE 
    d.`user_id`=3
    AND 
    (d.`poo`=1 OR d.`pee`=1)
    AND 
    d.`datetime` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
    AND 
    d.`datetime` <= CURDATE();
```

I tried using `LAG` but it is conditional on finding the last row that had an applicable bool value. For example, if these are the results from a query:

[image: query result example]

...then `LAG` would not work for `poo_diff` as the difference should be from the row that most recently had a `poo` of `1`.

How can I add this column?

Comment: Use, for example, correlated subquery in output. Provide sample CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, and desired output for provided data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the values you want using rolling variables:

```
SET @last_poo = '';
SET @last_pee = '';

SELECT 
    d.`datetime`,
    d.`pee`,
    SEC_TO_TIME(IF(@last_poo AND d.`poo`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @last_poo, d.`datetime`), 0)) AS `poo_diff`,
    SEC_TO_TIME(IF(@last_pee AND d.`pee`, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, @last_pee, d.`datetime`), 0)) AS `pee_diff`,
    IF(d.`poo` AND @last_poo:= d.`datetime`, d.`poo`, d.`poo`) AS `poo`,
    IF(d.`pee` AND @last_pee:= d.`datetime`, d.`pee`, d.`pee`) AS `pee`
FROM 
    `diary` d
WHERE 
    d.`user_id`=3
    AND 
    (d.`poo`=1 OR d.`pee`=1)
    AND 
    d.`datetime` >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
    AND 
    d.`datetime` <= CURDATE()
ORDER BY d.`datetime` ASC;
```

in this case, `@last_poo` and `@last_pee` store the last datetime for their respective event, while iterating on the selected rows.

Note that this won't work if you `ORDER BY ... DESC`, and I also had to swap some columns around, in order to have somewhere to update the variables after the difference is computed.

Finally, i'm using `SEC_TO_TIME(... TIMESTAMPDIFF(...))` because otherwise it seemed to produce some weird values such as `03:00:00.00000`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with window function `MAX()`:

```
select *,
  case when poo then sec_to_time(
    timestampdiff(
      second, 
      max(case when poo then datetime end) over (rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
      datetime
    )
  ) end poo_diff,
  case when pee then sec_to_time(
    timestampdiff(
      second, 
      max(case when pee then datetime end) over (rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding),
      datetime
    )
  ) end pee_diff
from diary
order by datetime
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=432d2b7d941e88651dff48166b42d638).